# How to Increase the Space Between Group Lables in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm creating a bar chart in Bokeh with groups, similar to this example:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_nested_colormapped.html

The problem I'm running into is that the group labels (so, in the example linked above, the fruit names) are running into each other if I put the font size just a bit larger to make it readable. The spacing is too tight. Is there a way for be to increase the spacing between the group labels and/or wrap the text of the group labels (for multi-word labels)?

I've searched the Bokeh documentation thoroughly, to no avail. I thought that doing something like `p.x_range.group_padding = 1.0` might do it, but that doesn't seem to help solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently (as of version `0.13`) any way to have multi-line labels. This has been recently requested in [`#8169`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8169) which you can follow for updates. (I can't speculate when this feature might be able to be prioritized).

In recent version of Bokeh, group labels can be rotated by setting [`group_label_orientation`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html#bokeh.models.axes.CategoricalAxis.group_label_orientation) on the axis, in case that is an option for your situation.

Otherwise, the groups pretty much already always take up the maximum available canvas screen space available to them. In order to make more space for them, you would need to make more space for them, i,e. make your plot physically wider or reduce the padding on the sides of the plot, or both.

That said, you might be able to get a little extra space by setting, e.g. the `group_padding` to *zero* (you want to remove empty padding space, not increase it).